# Upload Excel Codeigniter Error double primary key

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

I want to insert data from Excel with codeigniter, but I found something difficult for me. When I upload file, there is a some data double in primary key. I try to check it first before upload with

```
$cek=$this->m_admin->get_redudant($data['cells'][$i][2]);
if ($cek==0) {
    $this->m_admin->add($dataexcel);
    redirect('home','refresh');
}
else{
    echo "something wrong";
}
```

Here is function upload file:

```
function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './temp_upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls';           
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);                
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());          
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('error' => false);
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        $this->load->library('excel_reader');
        $this->excel_reader->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');

        $file =  $upload_data['full_path'];
        $this->excel_reader->read($file);
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

        $data = $this->excel_reader->sheets[0] ;
        $dataexcel = Array();
        $i=0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $data['numRows']; $i++) {
                        if($data['cells'][$i][1] == '') break;
                        $dataexcel[$i-1]['nip'] = $data['cells'][$i][2];
                        $dataexcel[$i-1]['nama'] = $data['cells'][$i][1];
                        $dataexcel[$i-1]['nipbr'] = $data['cells'][$i][3];
                        $dataexcel[$i-1]['tempat'] = $data['cells'][$i][4];
                        $dataexcel[$i-1]['lahir'] = $data['cells'][$i][5];
                        $dataexcel[$i-1]['temp_kerja'] = $data['cells'][$i][6];
        }

        delete_files($upload_data['file_path']);            
        $cek=$this->m_admin->get_redudant($data['cells'][$i][2]);


        if ($cek==0) {
            $this->m_admin->add($dataexcel);
            redirect('home','refresh');
        }
        else{
            echo "something wrong";
        }    
    }

}
```

I want to manipulate data in primary key. If data is exist , I will add data random in the end of id like

```
else{
        $x = rand(1, 1000); 
        $dataexcel[$i-1]['nip'] = $data['cells'][$i][2]."$x";
}
```

but it's not work , what should I do..

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
$x = rand(1, 1000);
```

you can define a global counter and increment, if data exists:

```
else {
    $counter += 1; 
    $dataexcel[$i-1]['nip'] = (int)$data['cells'][$i][2].$counter;
}
```